# Server Python script

Tags: python-3.x, server, port, portforwarding

I wrote a Python program that listens to a specific port number. I made port forwarding settings in ADSL modem. Now when I scan with an online scanner, I'm get port closed.
my vendor adsl modem =>linksys

```
import socket
import time
P = 1234
H = "0.0.0.0"
print (" server is started ",H," ",P,"\n")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((H,P))
s.listen(5)
con , addr= s.accept()
print ("connected by ",addr)
name=input("enter your name : ")
while True:
    dade=con.recv(1024)
    print(dade)
    if str(dade).find("EXIT")!=-1:
        break
    r=input ("replay >> " )
    if r=="EXIT":
        break
    r=name+" >> "+r
    con.sendall(r.encode("UTF-8"))
    print("waiting")
print ("\nExiting")
time.sleep(3)
con.close()
s.close()
```